# How do i disable vertical scrolling but enable horizontal scrolling in collectionview swift 4?

Tags: swift, collectionview

when I disable scrolling. It disabled for both horizontal and vertical.
how do I disable scroll for only vertical only?
[settings for collectionview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDHUD.png)

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to scroll collectionView in both directions. Either it will scroll horizontally or vertically.

User scrollDirection to specify your desired scroll direction.

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as?  UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I did not find any suggestions like scrollDirection = .horizontal or vertical in swift

Comment: @MitVariance Sorry my bad, I have updated the answer. CollectionView Layout manages scroll direction, so we need to change it using layout.